# I cannot connect with my containerized python web server

Tags: python, docker

My web server is based on `http.server` module, so the result of using it and using `sudo python -m http.server 80` and using `sudo python main.py` have to be the same.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3-alpine

RUN apk update && apk upgrade

WORKDIR /ClientConnector

COPY . /ClientConnector

EXPOSE 80

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

When I run the web server on my local machine i can successfully get `127.0.0.1:80`

but when i do

`sudo docker build -t container_name .`

and then

`sudo docker run -p 127.0.0.1:80:80 container_name`

what I get is infinity loading. But mostly, I get an error like "unable to connect"

I have checked, container successfully runs when I try to connect.

Comment: So, which is the question or the problem if it successfully runs ? Have you tried localhost:80 ?

Comment: can you share the logs of the container and the main.py code ?

Comment: @tremendows it runns but i cannot connect to it via http. i have tried localhost and all the rest network interfaces my machine have

Comment: i have checked. if i make an empty python container and run `python -m http.server` it will not work too( but works on my machine without container)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have checked documentation. It says i have to enable kvm. I enabled it and that is how i fixed the problem.